# How to force update of validation error indicator (red line)

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

In `App.xaml.cs` I've registered a validation error event handler, to revert all my `TextBox` controls to previous value (value in VM property) when a validation error occurs (e.g. if a `TextBox` bound to a double property is entered a string value).

```
public App()
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), Validation.ErrorEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_ValidationErrorEventHandler));
}

private void TextBox_ValidationErrorEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    DependencyProperty prop = TextBox.TextProperty;
    BindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(tb, prop);
    if (binding != null) { binding.UpdateTarget(); }
}
```

This works fine.  But the red line around the control remains and is never removed again when I enter legal values.  How can I force update of the validation, so that the red line is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to "clean" the value of the [Validation.ErrorTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the TextBox, by colling the [SetErrorTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.seterrortemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
private void TextBox_ValidationErrorEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        DependencyProperty prop = TextBox.TextProperty;
        BindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(tb, prop);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.UpdateTarget();
            Validation.SetErrorTemplate(tb, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. :-)